# Вывод уникальных строк

Tags: c#

Дан файл test.txt, в нем записаны строки:

```
epS3A
epS3A
epS3A
epS3A
bMkWY
bMkWY
bMkWY
bMkWY
```

На примере видно, что строки одинаковые, но нужно "не" показать все строки, а показать только одну из повторений, вывод на экран должен быть таким:

```
epS3A
bMkWY
```

Как это сделать, не знаю(

`Distinct`, **не нужно их удалять**, **надо показать их на экране**

пробовал считать и сравнивать как массив, но эффекта никакого, все равно все подряд показывает.

Цитата:
-Покажите вашу попытку с массивом

```
var repeated_string = 1;
string[] file1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Doe\Desktop\test.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < file1.Length; i++)
{
    if (file1[i] == file1[i])
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file1[i] + " " + file1[i]);
    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: повторяющиеся строки пропускать, только если они идут подряд?

Comment: Покажите вашу попытку с массивом.

Comment: @Igor ну типа та, да

Comment: @Doe вы сравниваете элементы с самими собой (`file1[i] == file1[i]`). Было бы странно если бы при этом выводились не все строки.

Comment: @Doe странно, зачем вы в цикле сравниваете каждое слово с самим собой и если они равны (а это всегда правда),то печатаете?

Comment: В общем, если файл не космических размеров, то я бы посоветовал считать все слова в память, отсортировать, далее достаточно знать только последнее напечатанное слово.Либо каждое напечатанное слово сохранять (только надо придумать, какую структуру использовать для скорости), далее проверять, было ли уже такое.

Comment: @Doe и чем плох `Distinct`? Изначальный массив `file1` он не испортит

Comment: В простейшем случае нужно два цикла вложенных использовать по i и по j. И сравнивать i-й b j-й элемент если i != j. В лучшем случае использовать HashSet<T> для проверки уникальности строк.

Comment: автор самоуничтожился

Comment: @АлексейСаровский `HashSet` вполне сойдёт. Или вообще использовать алгоритм на базе префиксного дерева

Comment: @АлексейШиманский видимо, познал дзен

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это был Komra. Не задерживайтесь, проходите мимо.

Comment: @Regent, Distinct использует внутри себя HashSet

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну вот.. А зачем я тогда отвечал? :(

Answer (score 1):

Вот рабочий пример решения задачи используя HashSet. Из вопроса не понятно,
нужно ли выводить неповторяющиеся только подряд идущие строки или глобально уникальные среди всех строк, моё решение для второго случая. Это один из самых быстрых возможных вариантов решения для глобальной уникальности строк, конечно если файл не слишком большой и его уникальные строки могут вместиться в память. ([запустить решение онлайн](https://repl.it/M3gp/0))

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MainClass {
  public static void Main() {
    string[] strs = {"ab", "bc", "ab", "ab", "bc"};

    HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < strs.Length; ++i) {
      if (!set.Contains(strs[i])) {
        System.Console.WriteLine(strs[i]);
        set.Add(strs[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Второе более короткое решение для того же случая глобальной уникальности строк можно сделать через Distinct метод. ([запустить решение онлайн](https://repl.it/M3rK/0))

```
using System.Linq;

public class MainClass {
  public static void Main() {
    string[] strs = {"ab", "bc", "ab", "ab", "bc"};

    foreach (string s in strs.Distinct()) {
      System.Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Если известно, что одинакоывые строки идут подряд, то он не самый быстрый.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так:

```
string last = null;

foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filename))
  if (line != last)
    Console.WriteLine(last = line);
```

А вообще, в коде из вопроса ошибка тут:

> ```
> if (file1[i] == file1[i])
> ```

Должно быть так:

```
if (i != 0 && files[i-1] != files[i])
```

Ну и выводить надо саму строку.

PS: Оба варианта работают только для подряд идущих одинаковых строк.